# Quicker way to convert UTC to EST and add 3 days to it

Tags: php

I have the following code, it works but is there a "cleaner" way, maybe less code?

```
$today = new DateTime();
$utc_today = date('Y-m-d', $today->format('U'));
$new_date = new DateTime($utc_today, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$new_date->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
echo $new_date->format('m-d-Y');
```

Comment: What format is your input date in?  Is it just a UTC timestamp, a string, or what?  Is it just a date, or is there a time component too?  And what format do you want your output data to be in?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to expresses the time right now, plus 3 days, in EST, then you're doing way too much work.  All you need is a single statement:

```
$date = new DateTime("3 days", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s\n");
```

If you are starting with an arbitrary UTC timestamp, then you need about 3 lines of code instead of just one:

```
// let us assume $inputTimestamp is the UTC time you want to play with
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$date->setTimestamp($inputTimestamp);
$date->modify("3 days");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s\n");
```

Alternatively, you could add 3 days worth of seconds to your timestamp and save a little code, but it is less readable that way:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$date->setTimestamp($inputTimestamp + (3*24*60*60) );
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s\n");
```

For date/time manipulation, I have found the PHP **[Relative Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)** documentation to be very useful.  It is definitely worth reviewing.